# Set Report Name in SSRS- Export report

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

I have designed a report from SSAS Data source. While exporting the report facing issue with report name. My report name "**Effort_Varience**", I want name something like this

- "Effort_Varience_**DATETIME**".
- "**DataSetName**_Effort_Varience_**DATETIME**".

Please help me, where to change in config file or any xml coding.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Report Viewer control on a web application, you can refer to the link below: 
http://www.jimandkatrin.com/CodeBlog/post/Setting-export-file-name-in-SSRS-report-viewer.aspx

If your are using SSRS in standalone way, there is no way to achive your requirement.